# Kinect SDK 1.8 examples Winbase.h error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, kinect-sdk

So i was working with kinect, my programs which i downloaded from the developer's kit were working fine. I simply downloaded the project and imported them to visual studio.

Then i wanted to try D3d color depth example. It stated that you need directx3D as a pre req. So i looked up and found out i need some windows sdk for it and i downloaded it.

Now i don't know what happened all of a sudden, but none of my programs actually work anymore they throw this error. I uninstalled what i downloaded but still nothing happens.

I'm new to kinect and c++ so i'm having problems in figuring out the problem.
Please help me out.

[image: This is the error that i see]

EDIT: I got it working. I was getting an error installing 8.0 after i removed it, so i was only able to install 8.1 sdk. But then again when i looked at the VC++ directories it had somethings like this $(FrameworkSdkDir) which still was referring to windows 8 sdk. which was non existent. So what i did is, i simply copied the windows sdk from my friends computer and pasted in mine. And it got working. Since i couldn't find a perfect solution. I believe this could be of some help to those who were facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you still have a version of Windows SDK present on your machine:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\*` being the origin of your redefinition conflicts.

If no other Windows SDK entries remain in your installed programs list, I would try deleting the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0` directory (perhaps move it somewhere else in case something goes wrong).

You can always re-download the SDK, should you need it later (or VS start yelling at you).

Comment: I don't think there is any. Can't find any. :\ SO what should i do now? any suggestions?

Comment: You looked in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` and didn't see a directory named '8.0' to remove?

Comment: I mean yeah i removed it (Stored somewhere else) . What should i do after then? should i reinstall the sdk?

Comment: Yes. I would just move the entire `Windows Kits` folder elsewhere and reinstall the SDK.

Comment: Alright i'll let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: alright so i installed it again. But now actually i forgot how do i refer this windows kit to my projects. I'm new to visual studio so i don't have any solid concepts.
So now i'm receiving error no windows.h because i think it doesn't know the path for the sdk. So where do i refer it? do i add them to additional includes? i don't want to configure this in all projects that i make. Isn't there a general space where i simply define it just once?

Comment: I now have windows sdk 8.1, but still i see sdk  8.0 referred in the macros.